# F# - Hex to ASCII

Tags: f#, hex

1. There is something better than *Convert* for the 2 operations in the following code?
2. I'd like to know if this solution (*sprintf*) is better (or worst) than one with the use of *Substring*
3. I'd like to know if using a *list* here would be better
4. The previous 2 questions change within the size of the string? (a short one (less than 20 chars) or a long one)

Assume the input is always correct (no odd lenght).

```ml
let hexToAscii (hex:string) =         
    let chars = Array.zeroCreate<char> (hex.Length/2)
    for i in 1..2..hex.Length-1 do
        chars.[i/2] <- Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToByte(sprintf "%c%c" hex.[i-1] hex.[i] , 16))

    String(chars)
```

Is a question like this better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 4):

A more idiomatic solution would be this:

First deal with a single byte e.g. "42"

```
let hexByteToAscii (s:string) =
    System.Convert.ToByte(s,16)
    |> System.Convert.ToChar
```

and let's have helper function to convert char[] to string

```
let charsToString (chars:char[]) =
    new string (chars)
```

Then let's deal with a longer sequence like "4142" by taking chunks of 2 characters and use our existing function to deal with bytes.

```
let hexToAscii (value:string) =
    value
    |>Seq.chunkBySize 2
    |>Seq.map ( hexByteToAscii << charsToString)
    |>Seq.toArray
    |>charsToString
```

You can test it:

```
hexToAscii "4142" // "AB"
```

In terms of performance both are asymptotically O(n) where n is the size of your input string.   I wouldn't worry much more unless your n> 10000.  Which doesn't seem to be your scenario.  Perhaps there's some gains to be made by implementing your own hex byte to ascii function using a dictionary table.